# Duplicate row based in column value

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

Please I need to duplicate row when having multiple values in one column.
Exemple  :

```
A  B  12  I76J-I76H=>
A  B  12  I76J
A  B  12  I76H
```

Thank you .

Comment: How many `max` values separated by `-` 4th column expects? will it be just two every time?

Comment: I think the max values i could have is 5 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit where credit is due big thanks to user @RichardTheKiwi for providing the majority of the code [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

Anyway here is the code. If you want to change the sql so that it doesn't separate based upon - just replace all - with the char of you choice.

Creating the table:

```
    create table Testdata(Data1 varchar(50), Data2 varchar(50), Data3 int, Data4 varchar(max))
    insert Testdata select 'A', 'E', '9', 'I76J-I76H-I76I-I76G'
    insert Testdata select 'B', 'F', '8', 'I76J-I76H-I76I'
    insert Testdata select 'C', 'G', '7', 'I76J-I76H'
    insert Testdata select 'D', 'H', '6', 'I76J'
```

Now updating the original table TestData

```
;with tmp(Data1, Data2, Data3, DataItem, Data4) as (
select Data1, Data2, Data3, LEFT(Data4, CHARINDEX('-',Data4+'-')-1),
    STUFF(Data4, 1, CHARINDEX('-',Data4+'-'), '')
from Testdata
union all
select Data1, Data2, Data3, LEFT(Data4, CHARINDEX('-',Data4+'-')-1),
    STUFF(Data4, 1, CHARINDEX('-',Data4+'-'), '')
from tmp
where Data4 > ''
)
INSERT INTO Testdata
select Data1, Data2, Data3, DataItem AS Data4
from tmp
order by Data1

DELETE FROM Testdata
where Data4 like '%-%'

select * FROM TESTDATA
```

Comment: Is there any way i can have the same results with ssrs options. or the only way is SQL.Thank you ,for the solution.